# Create a relation on itself for an abstract model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an abstract model:

```
@as_declarative
class Base(Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower() + 's'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

Several other models will be inherited from this model, each of them must have a relation to itself.

It is convenient to register this relation in the abstract model, so as not to write it in each child model.

But I have not found either in documentation or in discussions how to implement it correctly.

I assume that, it will be possible to do with this method:

```
...
@declared_attr
def parent_id(cls):
    return Column('parent_id', ForeignKey(cls.__tablename__ + '.id'))
```

But I am not sure of the correctness of this decision.